# Versions of the spectral theorem

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, sp.spectral-theory, von-neumann-algebras, operator-theory

Since any $C^*$-algebra can be represented as an algebra of bounded operators $\mathcal{B(H)}$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, the spectral theorem applies to all $C^*$-algebras:

($*$) $A=\int_{\sigma(A)}\lambda d\nu(\lambda)$ where $A$ is a bounded self-adjoint and $d\nu$ is a $\mathcal{P(B(H))}$-valued measure.

This can be generalized to self-adjoint unbounded operators, or restricted to self-adjoint compact ones.

But I read a lot of comments in books or papers (for example p.9 here: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0601158 ) that later it was proven that the spectral theorem is valid for any von neumann algebra $\mathfrak{M}$, with $d\nu$ a $\mathcal{P}\mathfrak{(M)}$-valued measure.

1) Since a von Neumann algebra is also a $C^*$-algebra, what new information does this "new" spectral theorem give?

2) Is the topology of convergence leading to equality in ($*$) the only difference?

3) If so can you explain why the von Neumann version is not presented as the most general one for bounded operators (since convergence in weak topology implies the norm one)?

Any further clarifications on the different versions of the spectral theorem are most welcome!

Comment: The new information it gives is that the spectral projections $\nu(E)$ always lie in the von Neumann algebra generated by $A$, though they will not in general lie in the C*-algebra generated by $A$.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer Mike. Could you please state the vNA version of the theorem in complete form or give me a reference where the point you made appears clearly? I can't find any.

Comment: Convergence in the weak topology does not imply convergence in norm.

Comment: You are right MTS, I was confused it's the other way around. I can't figure out how to cross the third question.

Comment: You may want to compare the continuous functional calculus and the Borel functional calculus.

Comment: With regards to 3.) In my experience the vN algebra version (ie Borel functional calculas) IS presented as the most general version. For me the way to think about it is not in terms of a the projection valued measure so much but rather in terms of the resulting isomorphism that it gives from the $C^*$ (or vN) algebra generated by $A$ and the algebra of continuous (or measureable) functions on $\sigma(A)$.

Comment: I agree with you Owen, that's one way of looking at it.  But the difference of properties of the projections appearing in $(*)$ depending on the version of the theorem is not quite clear to me, and Mike's answer is a first step in making things clearer. I guess it points out the fact that projections generate vNAs but not $C^*$-algebras, which is generally proven through the double commutant theorem; being a consequence of the spectral theorem is something I wasn't aware of, but as said, I was suspecting the spectral theorem had something to say about it..a reference would be really nice.

Comment: PS: all algebras mentioned above are supposed to be commutative. I'm not sure the spectral theorem has something to say about projections of a non-commutative von neumann algebra (which the double commutant theorem does)!

Comment: @Issam: Yes the spectral theorem does imply that a (non-commutative) vNA is generated by projections. Any vNA is generated by self-adjoint elements, to which you can apply the spectral theorem to get the projections. My perferred book for these topics is "An Introduction to Operator Algebras" by Kehe Zhu. It's quite expensive, though :(